# How can I transform an URDF file to an SDF file?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I want to know if there is any way to transform an URDF file to an SDF file.
How can I  transform an URDF file to an SDF file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53752/how-can-i--transform-an-urdf-file-to-an-sdf-file?/) by [Jey_316](https://answers.ros.org/users/3661/jey_316/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jey_316](https://answers.ros.org/users/3661/jey_316/) on 2013-02-01**:
it didnt work  @Alexandr Buyval

john@john-K53SD:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/bin$ ./gzsdf print /home/john/ros/01-myfirstyo.urdf

bash: ./gzsdf: (the file or the  directory doesnt exist)

Maybe it happens because I am using ros fuerte. What do you think?

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2013-02-01**:
it's broken in fuerte, please ticket.  Conversion works in groovy.  Here's another way to source setup in groovy:

source `rospack find gazebo`/scripts/setup.sh

then, you can run:

gzsdf print [your urdf file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

You can use the following command:

```
$GAZEBO_PATH/Gazebo/Bin: ./gzsdf print your_urdf_file.urdf
```

and copy result to sdf-file.

I used this method in Groovy.

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2013-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2013-04-25**:
which sdf version please? because it is not working for sdf 1.4 :(

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2013-04-26**:
It seems I have used the version 1.3. But I don't sure that it is important. Which version of ROS have you used? What is your error?

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2013-04-30**:
@Alexandr Buyval I tried in both fuerte and groovy. The errors were: XML Element[turnGravityOff], child of element[link] not defined in SDF; Error reading element ,,. But, after modifying the tags according to the new sdf format manually I could convert the urdf to sdf. thanks

**Comment by [Adam Allevato](https://answers.ros.org/users/21561/adam-allevato/) on 2017-10-12**:
In newer versions of gazebo, the correct tool is now a flag on the `gz` executable: `gz sdf -p my_urdf.urdf > my_sdf.sdf`